# IntelliJ Having problems running Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I created a new `LibGDX` project, and I wanted to test it out, so I created my run configuration, which is with the simple command of `run`. What ends up happening is the program seems to complete two loops, and then it freezes. If I close the program with the exit button on the window, it closes with the message `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, but if I stop it from inside IntelliJ, I get this error:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'file:/C:/Users/Michael/gradle-2.5-bin.zip'.
```

The Gradle distribution was originally a website URL, but I changed it because I thought it could have been a download or extraction issue.

Even today, I started up the program, and left it alone for hours, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means when you encounter error at one point, the error appears again while redoing it.This may help you : delete everything that were downloaded during gradle build, it might be inside user .gradle folder or hidden folder app. After that again create new project with everything you need for future too which might download all required components. Make sure your internet connection does not get disconnected during download. You may use LibGDX 1.6.2 jar file